# Eclipse unable to find gluegen/jogl (worldwind) runtime dependencies in GRADLE_HOME

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, dependency-management, worldwind

I have two projects; `main` and `library`. The `library` project uses `worldwind` so has dependencies on the `jogl` and `gluegen` libraries, and are defined in my `build.gradle` as follows:

```
dependencies {
    api "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.1.5",
        "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.1"

    runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.1.5:natives-windows-amd64",
            "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.1.5:natives-windows-i586",
            "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.1.5:natives-linux-amd64",
            "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.1.5:natives-linux-i586",
            "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.1:natives-windows-amd64",
            "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.1:natives-windows-i586",
            "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.1:natives-linux-amd64",
            "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.1:natives-linux-i586"
}
```

The `main` project has the `library` project as an `implemtation` dependency. Everything compiles and runs fine from the command line i.e. the runtime libraries are located within the `lib` directory of my distribution zip.

However, when I try to run/debug within Eclipse, the runtime `gluegen-rt.dll` cannot be found. This is because gradle downloads the dependencies to different directories within my `GRADLE_HOME` (from my local Nexus repo), but at runtime, they are required to be in the same directory (for the dll to be found, even though they are all on the classpath).

How can I get all of these dependencies to be in the same directory in my `GRADLE_HOME` for Eclipse to find them so I can run and debug my application? I would prefer to have as little Eclipse specific code in by `build.gradle` as this is not the only IDE we use.

Comment: You're right, the Java libraries must be in the same directory than the native libraries so that GlueGen can find the latter. There is something called "Native location" in Eclipse, maybe it can help. I use Gradle and Maven in JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation, you should look at my project to solve your problem.

Comment: Where exactly should I be looking in the [Ardor3D](https://github.com/gouessej/Ardor3D) project? I had a look, but couldn't find anything.